# im trying to use this code in module page and i called it from FrmEmployee using button to show all Employee information in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use this code in module page and I called it from `FrmEmployee` using button to show all `Employee` information in a DataGridView`.

`OpenDB` is a function to open connection using `OleDbConnection`.

```vb
Function New1()    
    Dim strcmd As String = New String("Select * From Employee")
    Co.CommandText = strcmd
    Co.Connection = Conn
    da.SelectCommand() = Co
    OpenDB()
    da.Fill(ds, "Employee")
    emp.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Employee")
End Function
```

Comment: Could you please format your question especially the code section? Otherwise it makes it hard to read and understand what you are asking. And besides that, what is the actual question or error you are getting? With what do you actually need help?

Comment: As for the issue, what's the issue?  A proper question is of the form *"I'm trying to do X, this is how I'm trying to do it, this is what happens when I try and this is how that differs from my expectations"*.  A FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem is required.

Answer (score 0):

Name your methods so they have meaning. Functions need a return type. "Get" implies that the method will return something and in this case it returns a DataTable of employees.

Keep you database objects local. Then you can control that they closed and disposed. `Using...End Using blocks do this for you even it there is an error.

You can pass the connection string (or a variable containing the string) directly to the construtor of the connection. Likewise, pass the sql statement and connection to the constructor of the command.

Keep the code in your DataAccess module separate from your User Interface code in the form. Don't update you user interface from the module.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Module2
    Function GetEmployeeDataTable() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Employee", cn)
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
End Module
```

Then in the Form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Module2.GetEmployeeDataTable()
End Sub
```

Comment: You must have clicked `Post Your Answer` Twice. Right?

Comment: @preciousbetine  Thanks, I guess I did and didn't realize.